# Multiple Scenario outline and Example in two different features file. How can I reuse the Java steps from one feature file to another?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, rest-assured

**Multiple Scenario outline and Example in two different features file. How can I reuse the Java steps from one feature file to another?**
***Feature -- > ANPost.feature***
**

```
Scenario outline : Verify csv file accept
When User perform the post request with localhost <port> <endpoint> <filename>
Then Response contains 201 and response message “Created”
***Example:***
|port|endpoint|filename|
|8080|api/v1/admin|AN.csv|
```

### **

***Feature -- > BNPost.feature***

```
***Scenario outline :*** Verify csv file accept
When User perform the post request with localhost <port> <endpoint> <filename>
Then Response contains 201 and response message “Created”
***Example:***
|port|endpoint|filename|
|8080|api/v1/admin|AN.csv|
```

---

> **ANPost.java** (Implementation code for ANPost.feature)
>   **BNPost.java** (Implementation code for BNPost.feature) 1, ANPost and BNPost are separefiles in feature folder. While implementing the same
>   steps in 2 different java file I got **“Duplicate implementation
>   error”**

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: For your case i agree with @Grasshopper. As a side note you can check [qaf-ws-support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki) which provides inbuilt steps for webservice automation. it supports xpath validation for xml response and jsonpath for json response.

Comment: @ user861594, do you have any real time example?Which could be helpful for my feature Testing. I am bit confused here. Thanks for your help

Comment: i added example as answer. There are lots of features which you can refer in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for same stepdefinitions to be defined in two different classes. Delete one of the classes, the framework will automatically pick up the matching step definition method by the regular expression matching. For each scenario all the step definition classes from the glue variable are loaded so any single implementation will work.

Comment: We have seen such real use cases and those are valid when you want to use same source of truth (single bdd maps to requirements)  applicable for different platforms or different channels. [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) has the provision to support that.

Answer (score 0):

with qaf web-service support you can write like below:

```
Scenario Outline: Search Keyword using data from file
   When user requests 'myservice.postfile' with data '${args[0]}'
   Then response should have status code '<status code>'
   And response should have status '<status name>'

Examples:
 | port| endpoint | filename | status code| status name |
 | 8080 | api/v1/admin | resources/testdata/AN.csv | 201 | Created |
 | 8080 | api/v1/admin | resources/testdata/BN.csv | 400 | BAD_REQUEST |
```

where `myservice.postfile` is request call and you can define request calls in xml like:

```
<requests>
   <myservice>
      <postfile>
         <baseurl>http://myhost:${port}</baseurl>
         <endPoint>http://myhost:${endpoint}</endPoint>
         <method>POST</method>
         <form-parameters>{
            'data':'file:${filename}'
         }
        </form-parameters>
      </postfile>
   </myservice>
<requests>
```

NOTE: This is just example, and it can be enhanced by using qaf features in best efficient way.

Comment: Thanks for the help user861594